# How to recover from OOM in WebGL in Safari when textures are too big?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, webgl

Safari in iOS seems to be artificially more resource limited (smaller texture or geometry size limits) than any other browser, and crashes often with WebGL scenes I'm making.

> <sup><sub>aside:  For reference, I'm testing in Safari on iOS 13 Pro, comparing to Chrome on Pixel 6 Pro, both two of the best phones, and I have no problems loading my WebGL scenes in Chrome at all, but Safari always crashes</sub></sup>

When such crashes happen in Safari, the web page is discarded, and the Safari tab shows the message `a problem repeatedly occurred`. There is no output to console, no error to catch.

How does one *catch* these problems, and for example, downgrade resources (for example, load smaller textures as needed)?

In my particular cases, these crashes happen when the resources loaded into WebGL are too big, f.e. lots of vertices in a geometry and/or large textures (f.e. large shadow map for light shadows).

The problem is, there does not seem to be any way to normally catch such errors (f.e. can't use try-catch), because nothing is thrown, the tab simply crashes.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: You can use window.onError

Comment: Ideally avoid the issue in the first place via user agent sniffing, like in the ol days.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Are you sure? I don't see any errors logged to console, so I would imagine that there are no errors being emitted. I'll try this next time I'm having crashes.

Comment: @LJᛃ I thought about that, but tech progresses quickly, it would be hard to keep sniffing code updated. Ideally we can programmatically adjust our levels of detail no matter the device (fully responsive).

Comment: I don't think `window.onError` will be helpful here, however rather than the tab crashing you *should* get a [`webglcontextlost`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/webglcontextlost_event) event, if you don't you might want to file an issue on the respective bug tracker.